# How to add elements of 2D array Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a 2D array : `[[1,2,3...],[4,5,6...],[7,8,9...]....]` and so on.

Now I want to add elements of all the row and make it 1D array. Please watch the expected result below:

I want my result to be addition of all the elements of every row: `[[1+2+3+...],[4+5+6+...],[7+8+9+...]]`

Comment: Did you attempt anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you can calculate the sum of the subArray and map that sum to each array using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const input = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
const output = input.map((item) => (item.reduce((acc, cur) => (acc + cur), 0)));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer what is "acc" and "cur" representing here?

Comment: You can know about it on this link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: `cur` means the current value, `acc` - Accumulator

Comment: `acc` Is the accumulator and `cur` Is current value , reduce will iterate the array and at each iteration will increase `acc` of `cur`